# How to use orderByKey() with DataSnapshot?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am populating a list of programs in a `RecyclerView`. Now i need to sort the programs by the time added. So i thought of adding a `timestamp` object to each program.

But i read that the `PushID` is also generated from a timestamp. So i tried to use the `orderByKey()`. But i can't figure out that how can i use the query with the `userSnapshot`?

**CODE**

```
public void FetchData() {
        ProgramItemList.clear();
        mRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        for (DataSnapshot programSnapshot : userSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            program = programSnapshot.getValue(Program.class);
                            ProgramItem item = new ProgramItem();
                            String pushID = programSnapshot.getKey();
                            item.setID(pushID);
                            item.setName(program.getTitle());
                            ProgramItemList.add(item);
                        }
                    }
                }
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            }
        });

    }
```

**JSON**

```
{
  "subscriptions" : {
    "han@gmail,com" : {
      "-KDnhRwHjssOejrqyenP" : {
        "category" : "Strength",
        "goal" : "This workout can be done while on the phone!",
        "length" : 1,
        "title" : "Hello Workouts",
        "weeks" : {
          "week1" : [ "High Knees", "Jumping Jacks", "Burpees" ]
        }
      },
      "-KDni3TN4NMyGXePyp92" : {
        "category" : "Strength",
        "goal" : "This workout can be done by a BABUJI",
        "length" : 1,
        "title" : "Indian Workouts",
        "weeks" : {
          "week1" : [ "Diamond Pushups", "Jackknives", "Pushups" ]
        }
      }
    },
    "obama@gmsil,com" : {
      "-KDnfjROKeFAL9wccsxY" : {
        "category" : "Mobility",
        "goal" : "afternoon body weight workout",
        "length" : 1,
        "title" : "Afternoon HiiT",
        "weeks" : {
          "week1" : [ "High Knees", "Squats", "Lunges", "Diamond Push-ups", "Lying Triceps Lifts" ]
        }
      },
      "-KDps90Dn6XtJc6Co00b" : {
        "category" : "Strength",
        "goal" : "goal",
        "length" : 1,
        "title" : "title",
        "weeks" : {
          "week1" : [ "Diamond Pushups", "Spiderman Push-up", "Wide Arm Push-ups", "Burpee Pushups" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
  }
```

Comment: You cannot call `orderByKey()` on a snapshot. But since a snapshot already contains all the data client-side, you can accomplish the same re-ordering in your own code. Also note that your digging yourself into a deeper and deeper hole with your nested data structure. There are many good reasons why [Firebase's documentation recommends keeping your data structures flat](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html#section-nested).

Comment: How can i accomplish it by re-ordering the code? or Do i have to add timestamp object & use `orderByChild`?

Comment: where is the timestamp?, You can either add an object and store the timestamp there. Or just make heavy priority adding. So every push you made is sorted already. You would have to delete the old data though.